# adding context information to the URL

Tags: html, url, web, contextpath

I need to add context or the current state of my website to the URL of the page.. So that if a user copies and sends the URL to another user. The other user can see the exact state of the website that the sender was watching, i.e. the tab he was in,and the data he was viewing. I have seen similar things being implemented in other websites like facebook, gmail, etc but I don't know how to do that in my application. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: can you provide any code you tried?

Comment: I need the approach and how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and friends to modify the URL to one which your server can use to deliver a page that starts in the desired state.